# Lyrics grammar parsing

Tags: meaning, slang, lyrics

There is a song by Larry Graham (*It ain't no fun to me*) with the following words:

> October sun is shining
>   These tears they cause the pain
>   **It simply make up
>
>   Only just to break up,** oh baby

What do the words in bold mean? If *it* is the subject, then why *make up* and not *makes up*?

Comment: I do not know the song and technically we don't explain lyrics  but -- I think it means they made up after a painful break up only to break up again. (Break up = break off their love relationship.)

Comment: Lyricists, like poets, are granted considerable [artistic license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license). Not only are lyrics not required or even expected to conform to any grammatical rules, they do not have to make any sense at all.

Comment: And don't forget the rhymes. In lyrics and poetry, rhyme can trump grammar. I don't know why anyone would want to parse lyrics to learn about grammar – you might as well try to learn arithmetic by studying the lottery.

Answer (score 1):

This is popular music, which often uses vernacular forms. Omitting the third-person *-s* inflection on present-tense verbs is very common in AAVE (African-American Vernacular English), and both the lyricist, Al Green, and the performer, Larry Graham, are African-Americans.